# UICollectionView header not showing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I'm working on a project that uses an `UICollectionView` to show several albums. The items show fine, but now I want to show an header above the first section.

To do this, I added the `registerNib:forSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:` to my init method. Like this:

```
[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"AlbumHeader" bundle:nil] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:kAlbumHeaderIdentifier];
```

(The `AlbumHeader` Nib contains a view of the class `AlbumHeader`, which is a subclass of `UICollectionView`.)

After that, I implemented `collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath` method:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind withReuseIdentifier:kAlbumHeaderIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Now it should try to load the header view, I suppose. But it doesn't, the method for the supplementary view doesn't get called.

What am I missing? Stuck for hours, have read the documentation on `UICollectionView`s many times, but nothing seems to help. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

After looking for the method yuf asked about, I read that by default the size of headers/footers are 0,0. If the size is 0, the header/footer won't display.

You can set the size with a property:

```
flowLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(0, 100);
```

Then all the headers will have the same size. If it has to be different for each section, you can implement the following method, which is part of the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == albumSection) {
        return CGSizeMake(0, 100);
    }

    return CGSizeZero;
}
```

Note that in vertical scrolling it uses the returned `height` and the full width of the collection view, in horizontal scrolling it uses the return `width` and the full height of the collection view.

Comment: To anyone still running into this issue, in order for me to make this work, I had to also give a size to 'collectionview.footerReferenceSize'. Not sure if that req is iOS 7 specific...

Comment: This is an incredible tip.  Thanks a million, Guido!

Comment: Enjoy that bounty!  :)

Comment: @JoeBlow Thanks, appreciated!

Comment: Instead of giving a constant height of 100px, is it possible to find the actual height of collection header view and return it back ?

Answer (score 3):

Did you implement:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

There's a ton of methods to implement just to make one thing work...I'm learning too. Tell me if it works.

Edit: Sorry wrong method. That is for subclassing I think. The one I'm talking about is in `UICollectionViewLayout` (the layout object you subclass, if your layout supports supplementary views):

```
- layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:atIndexPath:
```

See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UICollectionViewLayout

Comment: That method doesn't seem to be part of any delegates?

Comment: @GuidoH did you use FlowLayout or your custom layout? This answer refers to custom layout.

Comment: I did use the flow layout. The accepted answer solved it all, and makes sense as well. =)

Answer (score 3):

for **SWIFT 3 & SWIFT 4**

```
    self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "SectionCollectionReusableView", bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "SectionCollectionReusableView")



    self.collectionView.fs_width = self.collectionView.bounds.width

    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 70, left: 40, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 350, height: 140)
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: self.collectionView.bounds.size.width, height: 60)
    layout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
    self.collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

You have to add this to **ViewDidLoad**, and notice the

```
layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: self.collectionView.bounds.size.width, height: 60)
```

This will make the header Section Layouts

and Thanks @Guido Hendriks, and all I have got the insight from their answer as well