# UICollectionView Header xib not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I have a collectionview and I want to use a xib as the header. However, the xib will not appear. First I tried adding a label to the xib, which didn't appear. Then I set the whole background color to red. It it doesn't appear. The collectionview items leave a gap for the header, but it's completely blank. Similar SO threads are [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700432/uicollectionview-header-not-showing) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17463835/collection-view-header-not-showing-up), but as I'm not using storyboards and my header height is greater than zero, they don't solve my issue. Here is all my relevant code:

```
#import "ScoreboardCollectionViewController.h"
#import "ScoreboardCollectionViewCell.h"
#import "ScoreboardReusableView.h"
#import "ScoreboardModel.h"
#import "Scoreboard.h"

...

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Register cell classes
    UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"ScoreboardCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[ScoreboardReusableView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"scoreboardHeader"];


    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dark_fish_skin_"]]; 
}

...

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 34);
}

- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
           viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind
                                 atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ScoreboardReusableView *view = [[ScoreboardReusableView alloc] init];

    view = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
                                              withReuseIdentifier:@"scoreboardHeader"
                                                     forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return view;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my xib:
[image]

Answer (score 19):

OK, I solved it. The problem was that in my `viewDidLoad` method I had

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[ScoreboardReusableView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"scoreboardHeader"];
```

when since I was using a nib, it should have been:

```
[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ScoreboardReusableView" bundle:nil]
          forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
                 withReuseIdentifier:@"scoreboardHeader"];
```

Comment: Thank you! I had the same issue, this helped me resolve my issue. I hadn't realized that I also had a typo which caused me a lot of heartache even after I discovered this post of yours. But that is my bad.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing "Section Header" option of Collection View to enable:-

[image]